# How do I use command line to make an mp3 file an Mp4 file with visualisations? Is it possible to batch convert a folder with MP3's into videos?

Tags: command-line, mp3, mp4

I have a folder filled with mp3 files. I would like to render them as mp4 video files with music visualisations - is there a way to do this though command line?

Comment: MP3 files are music files without pictures. Where do you figure the video part will come from. And forget the command line for such a conversion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### General solution

**Use a program** created for video editing:
for example, you may want to check [AVIdemux](http://avidemux.sourceforge.net/), *a free video editor designed for simple cutting, filtering and encoding tasks.* that you can [download from here](http://avidemux.sourceforge.net/download.html) for Linux, Windows, Mac...

There's even a tutorial on [Create video from still image and from audio file](http://www.avidemux.org/admWiki/doku.php?id=tutorial:create_video_from_still_image_and_from_audio_file).

**By command line**:
you can download [`ffmpeg`](https://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html) and use it from command line. It exists for Linux, Mac and Windows.

### Bash solution (Linux /  Mac)

If we suppose that you are under Linux and you have all the needed packages and codec installed you can try something like:

```
ffmpeg -loop_input -i image.jpg -i sound.mp3 -shortest -b 1000k -acodec copy out.mp4
```

or

```
ffmpeg -loop_input -i image.jpg -i sound.mp3 -shortest -vcodec libx264 -vpre default -acodec copy out.mp4
```

To convert your `sound.mp3` file in `out.mp4` with the image `image.jpg`.

When you find the right combination of codec/options that you want, then you can do a script to read each file in the directory, strip the extension (.mp3)from the name and add the new extension (.mp4, `NewName=$(basename $MyFile .mp3).mp4`), select the image you want to put inside and execute the command that you have just found...

How to do the script is another question :-) and you can have some hint looking at [Filename Expansion](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-loop-over-file/), or to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20796200/3569208) or to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7290758/3569208). Please try to avoid to = parse the output of `ls`, use solution with `find` instead...

### Windows

It's possible to create a script too, or you can use some *freeware* or *shareware* software, among all [AVIdemux](http://avidemux.sourceforge.net/) or [Video Editor](http://filmora.wondershare.com/video-editor/)... or whatever the net will offer you.

**References**

- Internet your preferred search engine
- [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html)
- [Create video from still image and from audio file](http://www.avidemux.org/admWiki/doku.php?id=tutorial:create_video_from_still_image_and_from_audio_file)
- [Creating Youtube (mp4) from mp3 and image](http://forum.videohelp.com/threads/324202-Creating-Youtube-%28mp4%29-from-mp3-and-image)
- [How to Convert MP3 to MP4](http://www.wondershare.com/video-editing-tips/mp3-to-mp4.html)

Comment: First linux command worked fine for me, however I needed to change `-loop_input` to `-loop 1`.   I'm running Linux Mint 17.   Thanks.

Comment: On Fedora 25, ffmpeg works without -loop_input -i image.jpg.

Comment: -loop_input is deprecated use -loop 1 instead

Answer (score 0):

/sdcard/ghostbox $ ls        bank         output000.mp3   gbox         output001.mp3   image.jpg    output002.mp3   mp3tomp4.sh  recvol

How to run THE command om next Line 4 all *.mp3 files.

echo "rename the Source Mp3 File To audio.mp3"
echo "the Output Mp4 File Then Are video.mp4"
ffmpeg -r 1 -loop 1 -i image.jpg -i audio.mp3 -acodec copy -r 1 -shortest -vf scale=640:480 video.mp4
rm audio.mp3

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).